# Please show detailed steps of double integration of absolute difference

Tags: integration

Please show detailed steps of integration

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^1 0.5|x-y| dxdy$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\int_0^y(y-x)dxdy + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\int_y^1(x-y)dxdy$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\{y\int_0^ydx - \int_0^yxdx\}dy + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\{\int_y^1xdx - y\int_y^1dx\}dy$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\frac{1}{2}y^2dy + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\frac{1}{2} -y + \frac{1}{2}y^2dy$$

$$
=2/3 + 1/6 = 5/6
$$
I can't get the $\frac{2}{3}$ solution.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Maybe is a simple mistake. And please look up Mathjax, to see how to format your question.

Comment: I have used mathjax to make your question easier to read so now it is over to you to show us how far you got in your quest for the $\frac{2}{3}$ solution.

Comment: question modified @Andrei

Comment: question modifed @Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your integration limits. You integrate $y$ from $0$ to $2$ and $x$ from $y$ to $1$. But For say $y=1.5$ it's the wrong way around. If you integrate $x$ from $0$ to $1$ and then you split the $y$ integration from $0$ to $x$ and from $x$ to $2$, you get the right answer.

Comment: yes, forgot that point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The region of integration, $0\le y\le 2$ and $0\le x\le 1$,  is a rectangle in the xy-plane.  y> x, so |y- x|= y- x above the line form the lower left corner, (0, 0), to the upper right corner, (1, 2) and y< x, so |y- x|= x- y below it.  That line is given by y= 2x so the integral is $\int_{x= 0}^1 \int_{y= 0}^{2x} (x- y) dydx+ \int_{x= 0}^1\int_{y= 2x}^2 (y- x) dx$.